# Rerurn filtered array which is not equal to another array list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a api with list of car.

```
const getAsset = async () => dbApi('list_cars', ['', 100])
     .then(result => result.map(e => e.symbol));
```

here, `getAsset` returns the car list.

```
0: "BMW"
1: "HONDA"
2: "SCODA"
3: "STAR"
4: "PETH"
5: "TEST"
6: "TESLA"
```

In the below code block, I tried to return list excluding `BMW`. And it worked well.

```
 const getAsset = async () => dbApi('list_cars', ['', 100])
     .then(result => result.filter(e => e.symbol != 'BMW' ).map(a => a.symbol));
```

Now, I want to go forward and return the list of car excluding `BMW` , `HONDA` and `TEST`.

```
const expect = ['BMW','HONDA','TEST'];
```

expected result :

```
0: "SCODA"
1: "STAR"
2: "PETH"
3: "TESLA"
```

What changes should I make in the above code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by `filter` method, like this:

```js
const cars = ["BMW","HONDA", "SCODA", "STAR", "PETH", "TEST", "TESLA"]
const except = ["BMW","HONDA","TEST"];

const filteredCars = cars.filter(car => !except.includes(car));
console.log(filteredCars)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const getAsset = async () => dbApi('list_cars', ['', 100])
     .then(result => result.filter(e => (e.symbol != 'BMW' && e.symbol != 'HONDA' && e.symbol != 'TEST') ).map(a => a.symbol));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const cars = ["BMW","HONDA", "SCODA", "STAR", "PETH", "TEST", "TESLA"];
 
 const filteredResult =  cars.filter(e => (e != 'BMW' && e != 'HONDA' && e != 'TEST'));

console.log(filteredResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

I offen use lodash in my projects. It easy to do with this package

```
import differenceBy from 'lodash/differenceBy'

const myDifferences = differenceBy(Result1, Result2, 'value')
```